# Error 2308 when trying to RDP to DC when session limit reached

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I'm getting the error "Error Code: 2308 Error Description: Socket closed" when trying to establish an RDP connection to our Domain Controller but only when 2 users are already connected (session limit is 2)

If you try to log in when the session limit has been reached on the rest of our machines on this domain then the server will simply respond with the message that states, these 2 users are already logged in. Do you want to kick one off?

Any ideas what causes this?